how to create multiple task group in parallel using taskgroup decorator in Airflow
I would like to improve this DAG if possible.

from ... import....

with DAG(
    ...
) as dag:
   @task_group(group_id=f"group", dag=dag)
   def group(dag_instance, dataset, table):
        check_for_udpate = operatorhere(
        ...
        sql="select count(*) from {{ params.project_id }}." + dataset + "." + table + ";",
        )
        do_this_next = AnotherOperatorHere(
        ...
        )
        #dependency between the two tasks inside the taskgroup
        check_for_udpate >> do_this_next
#this portion below is what I want to improve so that I don't have to write each 1 by 1 if I have 10 or more of these
   t1 = group(dag, value1, ...)
   t2 = group(dag, value2, ...)
   #more to come here

#no dependencies between taskgroups
#this portion below is what I want to improve so that I don't have to write each 1 by 1 if I have 10 or more of these
t1
t2
#more to come here


What I want to improve in the script is already in the comments
Output will be:
group1 (2 tasks)
group2 (2 tasks)
group3 (2 tasks)
group4 (2 tasks)
group5 (2 tasks)
group6 (2 tasks)
and so on...
Update:
group.partial(dag_instance=dag).expand_kwargs(
   [{"key1": "a", "key2": "b"},
    {"key1": "c", "key2": "d"},
   ]
)

I got this error TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "MappedArgument") to str

Have a look here:
https://www.astronomer.io/docs/learn/dynamic-tasks#mapping-over-task-groups
This should suffice your use case.
Please share the entire code that you are using.

I udpated the question. thanks

@toyo123, can you share the entire DAG code so that I can review it properly and suggest the fix?
